# Does gulp-autoprefixer work with gulp-compass?

Tags: gulp, compass-sass, gulp-ruby-sass, gulp-compass

If I compile the scss with gulp-ruby-sass, gulp-autoprefixer works, but if a compile de scss with gulp-compass autoprefixer doen't work. This is the code:

```
gulp        = require('gulp'),
sass        = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
livereload  = require('gulp-livereload'),
prefix      = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
compass     = require('gulp-compass');


// Styles .scss files to .css
gulp.task('style', function(){
return sass('src/sass/style.scss', {
    style: 'expanded'
})
.on('error', sass.logError)
.pipe(prefix('last 2 version'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
.pipe(livereload());
});

// Compass to .css
gulp.task('compass', function(){
gulp.src('src/sass/*.sass')
.pipe(compass({
    config_file: './config.rb',
    css: 'dist/',
    sass: 'src/sass',
    style: 'expanded'
}))
.pipe(prefix('last 2 versions'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
.pipe(livereload());
});

// Watch with compass
gulp.task('watch', function(){
livereload.listen();
gulp.watch('src/sass/*.scss', ['compass']);
});

// Watch with ruby-sass
gulp.task('watch2', function(){
livereload.listen();
gulp.watch('src/sass/*.scss', ['style']);
});
```

**watch** task works, **watch2** task compile the scss but doesn't work autoprefixer.

Comment: Were you able to resolve?

Comment: @carlos, yes, would be interesting! I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

That might be not a direct answer to your problem, but you might consider to replace "gulp-ruby-sass" and "gulp-compass" with "gulp-scss" package which is way more popular and see if that resolves your issue.

Take a look on my setup, you might like it and/or find some useful information: [Reaper](https://github.com/melcma/Reaper/blob/master/gulpfile.js)